# How to read subscribe in Angular Unit Test?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write test cases of a component where at first I tried to check if a basic test case is working or not. There I encountered some errors related to Dependency Injection and solved those. Now the first issue that I am facing is mocking the API calls.

Below is my component code for which I am writing test cases:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientService } from '@service/http-client.service';
import { CustomErrorStateMatcher } from '@validator/error-state-matcher';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-prep-card',
  templateUrl: './prep-card.component.html',
  styles: ['legend { width: fit-content !important; }']
})
export class PrepCardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private _http: HttpClientService, private toastr: ToastrService) { }
  
  foamTypeList: string[] = [];
  colorList: string[] = [];
   
  ngOnInit() { this.getFoam_ColorList() }

  private getFoam_ColorList() {
    this._http.getFoamType_ColorList('ABC').subscribe(response => {
      this.foamTypeList = response.data.foamTypesAndColors.foamTypes;
      this.colorList = response.data.foamTypesAndColors.colors;
    });
  }
}
```

At first, I tried to run a simple test case to check if it is working correctly or not. Below is the test case I wrote:

```
import { ComponentFixture, inject, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { HttpClientService } from "@service/http-client.service";
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";
import { MaterialModule } from "src/app/material/material.module";
import { PrepCardComponent } from "./prep-card.component";

describe('PrepCardComponent', () => {
    let component: PrepCardComponent, fixture: ComponentFixture<PrepCardComponent>,
        _httpSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<HttpClientService>, _toastrSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ToastrService>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const _httpSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClientService', ['getFoamType_ColorList']),
            _toastrSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('ToastrService', ['success', 'error']);

        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [PrepCardComponent],
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialModule
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: HttpClientService, useValue: _httpSpyObj },
                { provide: ToastrService, useValue: _toastrSpyObj },
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PrepCardComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('test', () => expect('a').toBe('a'));
});
```

The above code snippet threw the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
> at PrepCardComponent.getFoam_ColorList (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/pages/prep-card/prep-card.component.ts:57:52)
> at PrepCardComponent.setFormFieldValidator (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/pages/prep-card/prep-card.component.ts:65:10)
> at PrepCardComponent.createForm (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/pages/prep-card/prep-card.component.ts:48:10)
> at PrepCardComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/pages/prep-card/prep-card.component.ts:28:10)
> at callHook (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:2542:1)
> at callHooks (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:2511:1)
> at executeInitAndCheckHooks (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:2462:1)
> at refreshView (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:9499:1)
> at renderComponentOrTemplate (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:9598:1)
> at tickRootContext (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:10829:1)

To solve this, I searched different questions here and saw common solution mentioned below to get an `observable`.

```
it('Call Service', inject([HttpClientService], (_http: HttpClientService) => {
    spyOn(_http, 'getFoamType_ColorList').and.returnValue({subscribe: () => {}})
}));
```

Writing the above test case was throwing an error (mentioned below) in the `subscribe` position.

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'.ts(2322)

**Service code**

```
getFoamType_ColorList(cardType: string) {
  return this.http.get<{ message: string, data: { foamTypesAndColors: { foamTypes: string[], colors: string[] } } }>
    (`${this.URL}/validate/foam-type-and-color/${cardType}`);
}
```

Can anyone help me out with how I can solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

As per dmance's answer am not getting any error while writing the test case but the test cases are still failing giving the same error. For reference refer below the full error log:

[image: error]

Comment: Did you try to return a mock of(YOUR_VALUE) instead of a subscribe implementation?

Comment: hey, it seems you have spied twice the same

Comment: @dmance can you tell me where to modify it? Not finding enough material for testing & I am new in this :')

Comment: I've added a more detailed example

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
spyOn(httpclientservice, 'getFoamType_ColorList').and.returnValue(of(YOUR VALUE));
```

This is a more complete answer:

```
describe('PrepCardComponent', () => {
    let component: PrepCardComponent, fixture: ComponentFixture<PrepCardComponent>;
    let httpClientService: HttpClientService;
    let toastService: ToastrService;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [PrepCardComponent],
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialModule
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
        httpClientService = TestBed.inject(HttpClientService);
        toastService= TestBed.inject(ToastrService);

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PrepCardComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('test', () => {
        spyOn(httpClientService, 'getFoamType_ColorList').then.returnValue(of(YOUR VALUE));
        // MAKE YOUR TEST
    });
});
```

Comment: there is no method as ```return```

Comment: @dmance edited your answer with `returnValue` instead of `return`

Comment: thanks, I've wrote without using my brain ;)

Comment: thanks. Am able to write like this but the error ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')``` is still showing & making my test case fail :(

Comment: I have attached a full error log screenshot for reference

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe

`spyOn(_http,'getFoamType_ColorList').and.returnValue(Observable.of(Your_Value));`

Comment: Tried to write this also but ```of``` was not recognized as part of ```Observable```. This was my import statement: ```import { Observable } from "rxjs";```

Comment: try import { of } from 'rxjs'; and returnValue(of(Your_Value))

Comment: Well thats then basicly what the guy below me wrote first :D